# How do I inject ASP.NET 5 (vNext) user-secrets into my own utility class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have already used:
    `user-secret set "AWSAccessKey" "my access key"` and
    `user-secret set ""AWSSecretKey" "my secret key"`

to get my keys into the secret store.

I've got this class that I will be using to send email via Amazon SES, but I don't know how to get my keys into it.

```
public class MailHelper
{
    public void SendEmailSes(string senderAddress, string receiverAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(
            new BasicAWSCredentials("[AWSAccessKey]", "[AWSSecretKey]"),
            RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
            {
                Source = senderAddress,
                Destination = new Destination { ToAddresses = new List<string> { receiverAddress } },
                Message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = new Content(subject),
                    Body = new Body { Text = new Content(body) }
                }
            };
            var response = client.SendEmail(sendRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I put in my Startup.cs in order to get those keys available in my MailHelper class? What needs to be added to the MailHelper class itself?

I've seen some examples for MVC Controllers, but I couldn't find anything for custom utility classes that are not already implementing some expected interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A class for your settings:

```
public class AwsSettings
{
    public string AccessKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AccessSecret{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

if your settings were in config.json you would do it like this:

```
{
  "AwsSettings": {
    "AccessKey": "yourkey",
    "AccessSecret": "yoursecret"
  }
}
```

in Startup you would need this:

```
services.Configure<AwsSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AwsSettings"));
```

your mailer class would need the settings injected into constructor

```
using Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel;

public class MailHelper
{
    public MailHelper(IOptions<AwsSettings> awsOptionsAccessor)
    {
        awsSettings = awsOptionsAccessor.Options;
    }
    private AwsSettings awsSettings;

    ... your other methods

}
```

UserSecrets is just another configuation source so instead of config.json you can put the settings there but you need to simulate the structure so it can map to your class so you set them like this with colons:

```
user-secret set "AwsSettings:AccessKey" "my access key" and
user-secret set "AwsSettings:AccessSecret" "my secret key"
```

that is equivalent to the structure I showed for config.json

now the settings will be loaded from user secrets and injected into your mailer

Comment: Okay, so when I inject them, how do I get to them? Back in the day I would use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[] anywhere in my app. How do I do that now?

Comment: I showed you, you now have an instance of AwsSettings inside your MailHelper and you can get the settings from awsSettings.AccessKey and awsSettings.AccessSecret

Comment: you should forget the idea of static access to configuration or any access to configuration other than in startup where configuration can be mapped to setting classes that will be injected where you need the settings

Comment: Please forgive me for being dense! But I mean, somewhere I have to say mailHelper = new MailHelper() and at that moment I will need to have the awsSettings to pass in, right?

Comment: no worries it is a major paradigm change, it took me a while to "get it" too, I kept trying to adapt the new framework to my old ways of working but gradually began to embrace the new paradigms

Comment: you don't want to new up your MailHelper it should be dependency injection all the way down, have MailHelper injected wherever you need it and let DI resolve the dependencies so in Startup you also need services.TryAddScoped<MailHelper, MailHelper>();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89820/discussion-between-chris-and-joe-audette).

Comment: don't forget to mark this as the answer if you are satisfied, I have a long way to go to catch up with you on reputation points :-)

Comment: @JoeAudette Can you explain how the same technique could be used to pass the connection string or any other asp.net 5 appsettings to a Data Repository Class Library (For example my DataLibrary.BaseRepository class which relies on the conn string). I am assuming we would use constructor injection. I don't have access to IOptions in my class library (package).

Comment: @BlakeRivell, inside of your ConfigureServices method you can register a POCO settings class that could be injected. See also [GIST](https://gist.github.com/rdefreitas/ba66505089a2784b7483167918bb5e56).
appsettings.json:
`{
  "GoogleApiSettings": {
    "ApiKey": "Store the Real Key in User Secrets for GoogleApiSettings:ApiKey",
    "EnablePlacesApi": false
  },
}`

Startup.ConfigureServices:
`services.AddTransient<IGoogleApiSettings>(provider => Configuration.GetSection("GoogleApiSettings").Get<GoogleApiSettings>());
services.AddTransient<IGoogleApiRequest,GoogleApiRequest>();`