# ConfigurationModel and Strongly Typed Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I liked the new ASP.NET 5 Configuration library, so I want to use it in a console application. It works fine for loosely-typed configuration. but I don't know how to use the strongly-typed version.

How to work from here? I have two classes

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Mpg { get; set; }
    public Paint Paint { get; set; }
}

class Paint
{
    public string MajorColor { get; set; }
    public string MinorColor { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration file:

```
<config>
  <vehicle>
    <description>Truck</description>
    <mpg>20</mpg>
    <paint>
      <majorcolor>white</majorcolor>
      <minorcolor>black</minorcolor>
    </paint>
  </vehicle>
</config>
```

How do I use that?

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.AddXmlFile("../../StrongeConfig.xml");
?
```

**First non-working solution:**

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\config.json");
var build = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddXmlFile(path);
var configuration = build.Build();
configuration.Bind(v);
Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
```

which gave me an empty vehicle.

Comment: typically the new way to do that is using the OptionsModel namespace to wire up instances of a class from config into services at startup. there are various config sources possible xml, json, user secrets, environment vars but they generally do the same thing and must be wired to classes that can be injected. http://shazwazza.com/post/using-aspnet5-optionsmodel/      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599573/how-do-i-inject-asp-net-5-vnext-user-secrets-into-my-own-utility-class/32608820#32608820

Comment: @JoeAudette I am not sure how to use that in this case. The code given in the page is for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.Test/ConfigurationBinderTests.cs#L400-L401

Build a configuration builder and the use it to bind to your strong type object

---

Updated:

```
class MyConfig
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

class Vehicle
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Mpg { get; set; }
    public Paint Paint { get; set; }
}

class Paint
{
    public string MajorColor { get; set; }
    public string MinorColor { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        config.AddXmlFile(@"x.xml");
        var configuration = config.Build();

        //Approach 1 (top level object)
        var topConfig = new MyConfig();
        configuration.Bind(topConfig);
        Console.WriteLine(topConfig.Vehicle.Paint.MajorColor);

        //Approach 2 (scoped)
        var vehicleSection = configuration.GetSection("Vehicle");

        var vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicleSection.Bind(vehicle);
        Console.WriteLine(vehicle.Paint.MajorColor);
    }
}
```