# ASP.Net 5 Logging in Class Libraries

Tags: asp.net-core

I am a little new to dependency injection. I'm trying to get started with ASP.NET 5 and am struggling to figure out how to use services in my ASP.NET 5 class libraries. Especially the simple things like logging and EF data access.

For example I have followed the guide here:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html

This has enabled me to have logging in the main application. How do I then output log events in my class library?

I'm aware that it is bad practice to reference the main application from the class library and wanted to figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: you just take a constructor dependency on ILogger<YourClass> and use dependency injection all the way down. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599573/how-do-i-inject-asp-net-5-vnext-user-secrets-into-my-own-utility-class/32608820#32608820) may help you

Comment: That was perfect. It was your comment at the end about adding it as a service. I couldn't shift away from "newing" up my classes... I'm not show how to give you reputation for this comment?

Comment: Glad that helped. you could just up vote the answer on the question I linked and that will give me some rep points

Comment: I've done that @JoeAudette Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a logger for your class by passing an `ILogger<YourClass>` in the constructor exactly like in the sample:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
     private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

     public (ILogger<MyClass> logger)
     {
        _logger = logger;
      }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("a log");
    }
}
```

Or pass an `ILoggerFactory`:

```
public class MyClass: IMyClass
{
     private readonly ILogger _logger;

     public (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreatLogger("MyClass");
      }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("a log");
    }
}
```

And resolve your class by [Dependency Injection](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html):

```
services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

Then you can use it in your controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyClass _myClass;
    private readonly ILogger<TodoController> _logger;

    public TodoController(IMyClass myClass, 
        ILogger<TodoController> logger)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This is what I have done. However, how do I call the class because it is telling me that I must provide the ILogger parameter?

Comment: Resolve it by [Dependency Injection](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html). I update my answer

Comment: Perfect. That's it. Thanks

Comment: What if I don't want or can't use DI, how can I still access logger?